# An example in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds (chain rule).

Tags: multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples

Spivak gives an example which has step that is giving me some problems to get it, even if it's supposed to be trivial.

Spivak says:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=\sin(xy^2)$. Since $f=\sin\circ(\pi_1\cdot(\pi_2)^2)$ then
>   $$f'(a,b)=\sin'(ab^2)\cdot(b^2\pi_1'(a,b)+2ab(\pi_2)'(a,b))\\ =\cos(ab^2)\cdot(b^2(1,0)+2ab(0,1)) \\=(b^2\cos(ab^2),2ab\cos(ab^2)).$$

The second step when he gets $f'$, how the $\pi_1'(a,b)$ becomes $(1,0)$ and $\pi_2'(a,b)$ becomes $(0,1)$?. Considering the first one, if $\pi_1$ is supposed to be the projection then according to Theorem 2-3(b) in the book must be $\pi_1'=\pi_1$ because of the linearity of the function, but then shouldn't be $a$ instead of $(1,0)$ since $\pi_1:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$?.

Comment: BTW, this is Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*. He also wrote a book named *Calculus*, which dealt with single-variable calculus. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard problem with the notation in multivariable calculus/analysis. We're evaluating the derivative of $\pi_i$ at the point $(a,b)$. The derivative of a linear map $T$ at any point in its domain is still $T$. In particular, $(a,b)$ is *not* the vector on which we're evaluating.

Comment: No difference in the finite-dimensional setting. You're confusing the notation: understanding the point you're evaluating at versus the vector to which you're applying the derivative — which Spivak never had in view here.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. Is like the theorem 2-3(b) where Spivak says that $Df(a)=f$, then here $\pi_1'(a,b)=\pi_1$, right?

Comment: When $f$ is linear, yes.